# How to find missing few gigs of RAM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I've just installed additional memory on my server so finally I have `16 * 16 GB Ram`, but in `ubuntu 18.04` I see the following:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory | grep  Size: | sed -e 's/Size://g' | sed -e 's/ MB//g' | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum " MB"}'

262144 MB
```

`free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G        527M        249G        1.7M        2.1G        249G
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
➜  ~ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      264110116      539420   261411708        1784     2158988   261964284
Swap:       8388604           0     8388604`

dmidecode says the [following](https://gist.github.com/zagorulkinde/9fd48224fc4c2706c6ae29e7544a9980).

`dmesg | grep drm
[    2.302878] [drm] Using P2A bridge for configuration
[    2.302982] [drm] AST 2300 detected
[    2.303384] [drm] Analog VGA only
[    2.303495] [drm] dram MCLK=408 Mhz type=1 bus_width=16 size=01000000
[    2.308711] fbcon: astdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.377220] ast 0000:09:00.0: fb0: astdrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.448093] [drm] Initialized ast 0.1.0 20120228 for 0000:09:00.0 on minor 0
[    2.455578] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00008100] Loading driver
[    2.456050] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:81:00.0 on minor 1`

I have `2 X E5-2690-V2`. 
cpuinfo:

`lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              40
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-39
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  10
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               62
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1200.569
CPU max MHz:         3600.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            5999.90
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-9,20-29
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   10-19,30-39
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d`

Also MB is:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASRock
    Product Name: EP2C602-4L/D16
    Version:
    Serial Number:
    Asset Tag:
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis:
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Why don't I see 256 GB in the output?

Comment: Is your server using an onboard GPU? Add the output of `dmesg | grep drm` to your question.

Comment: @NasirRiley added drm info

Comment: What processor and chipset is your server? You may be hitting a cap on the total physical memory space; 256 GB is the limit of a 48-bit address space.

Comment: note perhaps GB/GiBi as well.

Comment: @duskwuff added requested information

Answer (score 1):

With free command you can't get total ram available because it will show memory which is available for user space, when you install any operating system some memory reserved for kernel space operation. Memory is not missing but it is not showing up with free command.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: How to find full size of installed memory?

Comment: Please run this, you can clearly see installed and user memory difference.
$ sudo dmidecode -t memory|grep -i Size
 Size: 8192 MB
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7821         904        3191         398        3726        5951
Swap:          2047           2        2045